# Using aliases leads to some invalid identifiers

Tags: sql, oracle, alias

I'm attempting to create a table that lists patient identifiers for instances where a patient with a primary tumour of interest (MCC_IDS.TUMOURID) has been diagnosed with another tumour (AV_TUMOUR.TUMOURID) up to six months prior to the tumour of interest.

The columns have the same names in both tables (MCC_IDS and AV_TUMOUR), so I've added some column aliases. SQL Developer doesn't seem to like this as I keep getting 'invalid identifier' errors.

I'm not sure what else to try. Help!

```
    CREATE TABLE multitumours_hes_baseline
    AS
        ( SELECT mcc_ids.patientid,
                 mcc_ids.tumourid,
                 av_tumour.tumourid AS other_tumourid,
                 av_tumour.diagnosisdatebest AS other_diagnosisdatebest,
                 av_tumour.site_icd10_o2_3char AS other_icd10,
                 av_tumour.morph_icd10_o2 AS other_morph
            FROM mcc_ids left
          JOIN av2016.av_tumour ON mcc_ids.patientid = av_tumour.patientid -- Joining AV_TUMOUR onto MCC_IDS by PATIENTID to ensure that we can count TUMOURIDs other than those contained in MCC_IDS
--WHERE (AV_TUMOUR.OTHER_DATE>'31-DEC-2012' AND AV_TUMOUR.OTHER_DATE<'01-JAN-2016')
           WHERE mcc_ids.tumourid != av_tumour.other_tumourid
           AND ( mcc_ids.diagnosisdatebest >= av_tumour.other_diagnosisdatebest ) -- Only those conditions that occur in HES before the date of cancer diagnosis
           AND ( mcc_ids.diagnosisdatebest - av_tumour.other_diagnosisdatebest ) <= 182.5 -- Only those conditions that occur up to six months prior to the date of diagnosis
           AND av_tumour.dedup_flag = 1
        );
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the descriptions or DDL for both source tables, and the full error message you get?

Comment: Always show the exact error messages you are getting, always. And those are coming from the database, not SQL Developer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't refer to column aliases in the same level of query (except in an order-by clause), but you don't need to here.

You are doing:

```
WHERE MCC_IDS.TUMOURID!=AV_TUMOUR.OTHER_TUMOURID
AND (MCC_IDS.DIAGNOSISDATEBEST>=AV_TUMOUR.OTHER_DIAGNOSISDATEBEST)
AND (MCC_IDS.DIAGNOSISDATEBEST-AV_TUMOUR.OTHER_DIAGNOSISDATEBEST)<=182.5
```

The `OTHER_` names are the column aliases in the result set, so even if you could use those they wouldn't exist as columns on the original table, which is what the `AV_TUMOUR.OTHER_*` is trying to find. Use the actual column names:

```
WHERE MCC_IDS.TUMOURID!=AV_TUMOUR.TUMOURID
AND MCC_IDS.DIAGNOSISDATEBEST>=AV_TUMOUR.DIAGNOSISDATEBEST
AND MCC_IDS.DIAGNOSISDATEBEST-AV_TUMOUR.DIAGNOSISDATEBEST<=182.5
```

And you can't refer to the column alias without the table prefix - i.e. `WHERE MCC_IDS.TUMOURID!=OTHER_TUMOURID` - because it is the same level of query, and because of how the query is parsed internally; [from the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html):

> ***c_alias***
>   Specify an alias for the column expression. ... The alias effectively renames the select list item for the duration of the query. The alias can be used in the *`order_by_clause`* but not other clauses in the query.

---

Also, not really relevant, but to search back six months you could do:

```
LEFT JOIN AV_TUMOUR ON AV_TUMOUR.PATIENTID = MCC_IDS.PATIENTID
WHERE AV_TUMOUR.OTHER_TUMOURID != MCC_IDS.TUMOURID
AND AV_TUMOUR.OTHER_DIAGNOSISDATEBEST >= ADD_MONTHS(MCC_IDS.DIAGNOSISDATEBEST, -6)
AND AV_TUMOUR.DEDUP_FLAG=1
```

You are using a left outer join, but because you have conditions in the `WHERE` clause as well that is effectively turning it back into an inner join. Unless you want to see `MCC_IDS` with *don't* have another tumour in that period, you can remove 'LEFT':

```
JOIN AV_TUMOUR ON AV_TUMOUR.PATIENTID = MCC_IDS.PATIENTID
WHERE AV_TUMOUR.OTHER_TUMOURID != MCC_IDS.TUMOURID
AND AV_TUMOUR.OTHER_DIAGNOSISDATEBEST >= ADD_MONTHS(MCC_IDS.DIAGNOSISDATEBEST, -6)
AND AV_TUMOUR.DEDUP_FLAG=1
```

If you do want to see those, which seems unlikely from your description, then make all the conditions part of the `ON`:

```
LEFT JOIN AV_TUMOUR ON AV_TUMOUR.PATIENTID = MCC_IDS.PATIENTID
AND AV_TUMOUR.OTHER_TUMOURID != MCC_IDS.TUMOURID
AND AV_TUMOUR.OTHER_DIAGNOSISDATEBEST >= ADD_MONTHS(MCC_IDS.DIAGNOSISDATEBEST, -6)
AND AV_TUMOUR.DEDUP_FLAG=1
```

Comment: I cannot convey how appreciative I am for your help on this. I have tonnes of SQL work to do, but never touched it until a few weeks ago. This is one in a long line of simple mistakes that have taken up more time and caused more grey hairs than would be ideal. Thank you especially for explaining the error rather than posting a correction by itself. A massive help..

Comment: @user518206 . . . In Stack Overflow you can show your appreciation by accepting the answer.